# Urban airship Android stop default alert message when click on notification

Tags: android, urbanairship.com

how can we prevent default alert from urban airship when we click on notification if app is in background. Is there any configuration to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by default alert? If you are referring to how to deal with the default notification open behavior you can by specifying a custom broadcast, see http://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/android.html#listening-for-push-events.